# Where does one find the API and secret key?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, interface-builder

How do I find the API and secret key? I've searched your answers but they seem outdated as I can't find the links the instructions are referring to.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

You have to create an App to get App Id and App Secret.